# SEL4 User-space drivers Example

Tags: device-driver, usb-drive, microkernel, sel4

I am trying to write sample usb driver for sel4 in userspace. can anybody have an idea about sel4 user-space driver please share with me...
  If anyone have example code for sel4 user-space driver(sample drivers) please share with me...

Comment: have you accomplished it?

Comment: Could somebody with 1500+ reputation create a tag "seL4", so it could be added here?  Seems there is some work in a seL4 specific Q/A site for stack overflow: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/120611/sel4

Comment: Pleas consider asking this on our proposal above ^ and also on the seL4 developer's mailing list: https://sel4.systems/lists/listinfo/devel or irq channel: https://docs.sel4.systems/IRCChannel. We're trying to build a better community for seL4 developmenton stack overflow, but it's still a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

seL4 is a microkernel. its architecture is base on transfer most of kernel modules (for example filesystem driver, network stack driver , ... ) to user space area.
so in its repository  all driver like libusbdrivers, libethdrivers ,libsdhcdriver ,... work in user space mode. so you can check them.